"Topological surface operator" in a Euclidean field theory
The question stems from Thomas Dumitrescu's lecture on generalized symmetry.  The lecture notes can be found here.  But this is way before we get to generalized symmetry.  My question is about eq. (5.4) in the lecture notes, on how an ordinary symmetry generator acts on a local operator.
An ordinary (0-form) symmetry is characterized by a conserved Noether current $j_{\mu}$.  In 4d Lorentzian spacetime, the total conserved charge/symmetry generator is
$$
Q = \int_{space} d^3 \vec{x}\, j_0.
$$
I know how to define equal-time commutators through canonical quantization.  $Q$ has no time dependence because it commutes with the Hamiltonian.  Given a local operator $\mathcal{O}(x)$, its charge $q$ can be probed by the commutator $$[Q, \mathcal{O}(x)] = iq \mathcal{O}(x).$$  It sounds all good.
But I am confused when we get to Euclidean space.  We can replace the spatial integral with any closed 3-surface $\Sigma_3$ in the integration and define
$$
Q[\Sigma_3] = \int_{\Sigma_3} j_{\perp}
$$
and supposedly we find the charge of a local operator now by considering
$$
Q[\Sigma_3] \mathcal{O}(x) = q\mathcal{O}(x) \tag{*}
$$
if $x$ is inside $\Sigma_3$.
My question: how is the LHS of (*) defined?

clearly the canonical language is not applicable

do I insert them into some path integral and show the equivalence of two sides within correlation functions?

how do I even do that in practice?  For example, how to find the charge of complex scalar field $\phi(x)$ in a free theory with $U(1)$ symmetry?



The precise statement is that if you compute the correlator $\langle j_\perp(y) {\cal O}(x) O_1(x_1) \cdots O_n(x_n) \rangle$, then integrate $y$ over $\Sigma_3 = \partial R$, then as long as $x \in R$ and $x_k \not\in R$, the correlator reduces to $q \langle {\cal O}(x)  O_1(x_1) \cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle$.

Thanks for clarification.  Though, is this something even doable in practice?  Like, can I actually infer the charge of $\phi(x)$ this way?

You can do this as long as you know the correlator, which can be evaluated using bootstrap techniques or the path integral. That being said, most of the time, the identity is used in the other direction. Knowing the charge of $\phi(x)$, we can use the identity to constrain correlators.
